# IDE with step-through debugger for Adobe Air / Java application

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm looking for an IDE to use for creating an Air interface to a desktop Java application (using something like Merapi for Air / Java connectivity). I'm only interested in debugging ActionScript and Java (no mxml, JavaScript, or AJAX).

I've used a previous version of the FlexBuilder Eclipse plugin that had step-through debugging. You could debug through the Flex code and also step into and debug the Java code on the server. (Unfortunately the debugger is broken in the current version of Flex Builder so I'm looking for something else.)

Netbeans has support for Flex and Aptana has a plugin for Air, but I don't know if either supports debugging.

Any recommendations?

Thanks.

Dean

Comment: Im pretty sure aptana has debugging

Comment: It doesn't look like Aptana supports debugging both ActionScript and Java, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard from Arnaud Vincent who develops the FlexBean plugin for NetBeans and it doesn't have ActionScript debugging yet.

It looks like the answer to my question is no.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search didn't come up with any promising results, so i am going to guess that debugging is not currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK IntelliJ IDEA has Flex debugging support.